# I have created a class for executing actions, but which extendable design pattern should I actually use here?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, reflection

I have created a class which can execute methods by a string code (this is what I want actually, since the (**already existing**) database contains these codes. However I want this to be more extendible as I add more database records. For now we have to create a method for each code, but I want to use an interface and a class which can be created without editing this class. Do you guys have any suggestions?

```
   public class SpecificAction
    {
    public ActionToPerform ActionToPerform { get; private set; }        
    public string Action { get { return ActionToPerform.Action.Code; } }


    public SpecificAction(ActionToPerform actionToPerform)
    {
        ActionToPerform = actionToPerform;
    }

    public dynamic Execute(object[] parametersArray = null)
    {
        Type type = typeof (SpecificAction);

        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(Action);

        dynamic result = null;
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            result = methodInfo.Invoke(this, parameters.Length == 0 ? null : parametersArray);
        }
        return result != null && result;
    }

    //"Restart" is one of the codes in the database
    public bool Restart()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //"AddToEventLog" is one of the codes in the database
    public bool AddToEventLog()
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("Actions"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("Actions", "Application");
        }
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Actions", Action + "is executed", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
        return true;
    }

    //"SendEmail" is one of the codes in the database
    public bool SendEmail()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I call it like this and it works:

```
        bool isPerformed = false;

        var action = new SpecificAction(actionToPerform);
        isPerformed = action.Execute();
```

However, I would find it way better to implement a class for each possible action and dynamically execute a method in there, is this possible with some of the existing patterns, could you give me an example, since I have already tried a lot?

Comment: This really belongs on codereview, or possibly programmers.

Comment: @Servy you're right actually. However I find that people here helped me a lot on this kind of questions and it contributes to the platform since there is also code that could really help other people here with actual problems.

Comment: You should not knowingly post questions on the wrong place.  That's *much* worse than simply not knowing the correct place to post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this type of problem is solved using the Command Pattern.

The command pattern "encapsulates all the information required to call a method at a later date."

[More on the command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

The Command pattern usually employs an abstract base class (or an interface) `Command` from which we build up an inheritance hierarchy of commands. In this way we do not need to know exactly what command will execute at runtime, only the interface required to invoke it.

Comment: I was thinking about this, however it does not exactly fit for my situation, since I am also using reflection. Could you possibly give an example, that is if you have the time of course.

Comment: Is there any particular need for you to use reflection? Can you redesign without it?

Comment: I probably can't since the methods have to be executed by a string code. It doesn't matter if the method name or the class name represents the string

Comment: I have added more information about the command pattern and how to implement it

Comment: In a project I am working on I've encountered the same problem and have also tackled it by abstracting a common interface that is the same for every command. New commands simply extend the common interface and handle any additional calls within themselves, to keep a simple API to the callee.